# using date range to convert month end data to weekly data on Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a dataframe that looks like the following. It is month end data.

```
date ,     value , expectation
31/01/2020, 34,     40
28/02/2020, 35,     38
31/03/2020, 40,     44
```

What I need:

```
date ,     value , expectation

07/01/2020, 0,       0 
14/01/2020, 0,       0
21/01/2020, 0,       0
28/01/2020, 0,       0 
04/02/2020, 34,     40
11/02/2020, 0,       0
18/02/2020, 0,       0
25/02/2020, 0,       0
04/03/2020, 35,     38
```

Basically, I am trying to convert the month end data to weekly data. But, the twist is that the exact month-end-date may not match the weekly date range, so it will fall into the end of week date (e.g., 04/02/2020 for 31/01/2020). The other week-end date are filled with 0. It sounds messy. But this what I have tried.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', index_col=0)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%d/%m/%y')

dtr = pd.date_range('01.01.2020', '31.03.2020', freq='W')

empty = pd.DataFrame(index=dtr)

df = pd.concat([df, empty[~empty.index.isin(df.index)]]).sort_index().fillna(0)
```

The code works but I do not get the exact expected output. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%d/%m/%Y')

dtr = pd.date_range('01.01.2020', '31.03.2020', freq='W')
empty = pd.DataFrame(index=dtr)


df = pd.merge_asof(empty, 
                   df, 
                   left_index=True, 
                   right_index=True, 
                   tolerance=pd.Timedelta(7, 'd')).fillna(0)
print (df)
            value  expectation
2020-01-05    0.0          0.0
2020-01-12    0.0          0.0
2020-01-19    0.0          0.0
2020-01-26    0.0          0.0
2020-02-02   34.0         40.0
2020-02-09    0.0          0.0
2020-02-16    0.0          0.0
2020-02-23    0.0          0.0
2020-03-01   35.0         38.0
2020-03-08    0.0          0.0
2020-03-15    0.0          0.0
2020-03-22    0.0          0.0
2020-03-29    0.0          0.0
```

---

If need also change start of weeks, e.g from Tuesdays change `freq` in `date_range`:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%d/%m/%Y')

dtr = pd.date_range('01.01.2020', '31.03.2020', freq='W-Tue')
empty = pd.DataFrame(index=dtr)

df = pd.merge_asof(empty, 
                   df, 
                   left_index=True, 
                   right_index=True, 
                   tolerance=pd.Timedelta(7, 'd')).fillna(0)
print (df)
            value  expectation
2020-01-07    0.0          0.0
2020-01-14    0.0          0.0
2020-01-21    0.0          0.0
2020-01-28    0.0          0.0
2020-02-04   34.0         40.0
2020-02-11    0.0          0.0
2020-02-18    0.0          0.0
2020-02-25    0.0          0.0
2020-03-03   35.0         38.0
2020-03-10    0.0          0.0
2020-03-17    0.0          0.0
2020-03-24    0.0          0.0
2020-03-31   40.0         44.0
```

Comment: I am getting a value error. "ValueError: right keys must be sorted".

Comment: It gives a type error. TypeError: Cannot change data-type for object array.

Comment: it says dtype:object

Comment: So astype does not work. I used infer_objects(). It works for date but I do not get any values for the other columns (only 0). The only change in the code was df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', dtype='object')
df = df.infer_objects()
df = df.sort_index()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220848/discussion-between-non-linear-and-jezrael).

Comment: For correct working is necessary DatetimeIndex in original `df` for matching by `empty.index`, which is also `DatetimeIndex`

Answer (score 0):

Below given piece of code will give you the desired result:

```
for end_date in df["date"]:
    days_diff = (end_date  - pd.date_range(end=end_date , freq='W', periods=5)[-1])
    pd.date_range(end='2020-03-31', freq='W', periods=5) + days_diff
```